# What is the correct value of 'rescale_grad' in case of multi-GPU machine?

Tags: deep-learning, keras, mxnet

My batch size is 512, I have 8 GPUs

Should I define:
*rescale_grad* = 1. / 512 **or** *rescale_grad* = 1. / (8*512)

Thanks!

Comment: Increasing the batch size does not guarantee that a larger learning rate will work. However you can check out this recent Facebook paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.02677.pdf for some strategies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Batch size is something that is tied to the computer and not to the GPU. Quote (from [here](https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/how_to/multi_devices.html)):

> Workload Partitioning
>
> By default, MXNet partitions a data batch evenly among the available
>   GPUs. Assume a batch size b and assume there are k GPUs, then in one
>   iteration each GPU will perform forward and backward on b/k examples.
>   The gradients are then summed over all GPUs before updating the model.

In your case `b` is 512. Therefore you should be using `rescale_grad = 1. / 512`